# Абстрактные классы и интерфейсы

Tags: java, классы, интерфейс

Всем привет!

Есть абстрактный класс:

```
public abstract class Beta {
    public abstract void method1(); 
}
```

Есть интерфейс:

```
public interface Alpha {
    public void method1(); 
}
```

Класс для теста:

```
public class Testing extends Beta implements Alpha {

     @Override
     public void method1() {
         System.out.print("!"); 
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) { 
         Testing test = new Testing();
         test.method1();
     } 
}
```

Вопрос состоит в том, чей метод будет вызван при запуске: Абстрактного класса или Интерфейса?

Comment: @SuperHuman, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Да вроде так и сделал. Если все равно не правильно, буду рад узнать :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разумеется, ни тот ни другой: их обоих не существует.

Вызовется реальная имплементация: `Testing.method1`.

Дело в том, что и абстрактный метод, и метод интерфейса — не методы, а лишь гарантии программисту (и компилятору!), что класс верхнего уровня такой метод заимплементирует. Для вашего класса `Testing` наличие метода `method1` гарантировано двумя различными источниками: интерфейсом и абстрактным классом.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный и развернутый ответ. :)

Answer (score 4):

В общем-то соглашусь с [[@Vlad](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd) - вы вызываете конкретную реализацию из Testing, однако тут стоит отметить одну деталь. Логически это можно рассматривать так:

```
Testing first = new Testing();
first.method1() // здесь можно считать, что вы вызываете метод класса Testing

Alpha first = new Testing();
first.method1() // здесь можно считать, что вы вызываете метод интерфейса

Beta second = new Testing();
second.method1() // здесь можно считать, что вы вызываете метод абстрактного класса
```

То есть ответ зависит от того, в качестве чего вы рассматриваете ваш экземпляр - в качестве Alpha, Beta или Testing. Разницы в выполнении нет (во всех случаях вызовется Testing::method1()) однако разница может иметь место на логическом уровне - у каждой из трех сущностей есть свой набор методов, которыми она может оперировать, и если в данном примере все три сущности  имеют одинаковый интерфейс, то в других случаях они не будут столь же взаимозаменяемы

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь все стало на свои места. :)

Тут я знал, чей метод будет вызван:
Alpha first = new Testing();
Beta second = new Testing();